# Why does the print statement change the value of pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I wrote a c++ code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    int i2 = 0;
    void *pi = &i - 1;
    cout << "by cout - the value of *pi is: " << *(int*)pi << endl;
    printf("by printf - the value of *pi is: %d\n", *(int*)pi);
    printf("the address of pi is: %p\n", pi);
    printf("the address of i2 is: %p\n", (void*)&i2);
    printf("the value of i2 is: %d\n", i2);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
by cout - the value of *pi is: 0
by printf - the value of *pi is: 0
the address of pi is: 0029fe94
the address of i2 is: 0029fe94
the value of i2 is: 0
```

---

now if I remove the statement which will print the address.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    int i2 = 0;
    void *pi = &i - 1;
    cout << "by cout - the value of *pi is: " << *(int*)pi << endl;
    printf("by printf - the value of *pi is: %d\n", *(int*)pi);
    // printf("the address of pi is: %p\n", pi);
    // printf("the address of i2 is: %p\n", (void*)&i2);
    printf("the value of i2 is: %d\n", i2);
    return 0;
}
```

now the output is:

```
by cout - the value of *pi is: 2004212408
by printf - the value of *pi is: 2004212408
the value of i2 is: 0
```

notice that the value was totally different.

update:
If I add some assignment after the print:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    int i2 = 0;
    void *pi = &i - 1;
    cout << "by cout - the value of *pi is: " << *(int*)pi << endl;
    printf("by printf - the value of *pi is: %d\n", *(int*)pi);
    // printf("the address of pi is: %p\n", pi);
    // printf("the address of i2 is: %p\n", (void*)&i2);
    pi = &i2;
    printf("the value of i2 is: %d\n", i2);
    return 0;
}
```

the output been normal again:

```
by cout - the value of *pi is: 0
by printf - the value of *pi is: 0
the value of i2 is: 0
```

use "g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall" to compile, version is 4.9.2.

Why could that happen?

Comment: WTF: `void *pi = &i - 1;` and `*(int*)pi` (In other words: You do not know, what are you doing, please read some books)

Comment: Please see the output of `g++ -S`.

Comment: @DieterLücking apologize for that, It's an accident to find the difference.. I will never use that in other situation. Thank you.

Comment: @timrau I'm reading the assembly code now，thank you. But I think I really got the feeling of `undefined` now.

Answer (score 8):

Accessing `pi` is undefined behaviour due to the fact that `&i - 1` might not be a valid pointer value.

In standardese (from the C++ standard), at §5.3.1/3 we have:

> [...] For purposes of pointer arithmetic (5.7) and comparison (5.9, 5.10), an object that is not an array element whose address is taken in this way is considered to belong to an array with one element of type T.

which leads us to §5.7/4:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression. [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Basically every problem in your C++ program can be explained with undefined behavior.

Comment: The C++ standard has adopted this wording, by the way. See §5.7/4.

Comment: That is `undefined`, ok I think I really understood that meaning now. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, thanks. I've updated with the C++ standard quotes.

Comment: _"`&i - 1` might not be a valid pointer value"_ Doesn't matter if it happens to map to some object: you went out of bounds of `i` itself and so you've already invoked UB. Everything after that is moot.

Comment: Yes I saw what is `undefined behaviour` on the book, but never distinguish between that and `unvalid` until this time.

Comment: @piratf: Please stop writing things that are not code inside `code formatting`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I checked the documents just now, Do you mean the "output" part? Could you tell me what should I do to correct that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Please stop writing things that are not code inside `code formatting`" That makes me confused..

Comment: @piratf It was more a response to your comment here than a comment about your question. "undefined behaviour" is not code. "unvalid" is not code. Please don't mark them as code. For your question, for your "output" part, ideally don't mark it as code (use `<pre>` instead, that way you don't get invalid syntax highlighting), but marking that as code is less bad than the random words.

Comment: @hvd I changed the content of the question now, please let me know if there is any other bad place. Thank you so much for the kind direction.

Comment: @piratf You asked your question pretty well, I think. There's always room for improvement, but it looks pretty solid to me as it is.

Comment: @piratf: Oh, that. Yes, you were `writing comments like this`. The question was fine; in fact I keep rolling back the edits that break it. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I noted that, could you let me know "do that roll back" to break what? like to break write things use "inline code span"?

Comment: @piratf: I don't understand what you're saying, sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't mind, I think I got it already. end of the question, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as has been said already, your program has undefined behaviour. You just can't hack around with pointers like this and expect consistent behaviour.

Why? Because compilers are complicated creatures that do all sorts of weird magic that would ruin your expectations of memory layout.

In this case, you are just *assuming* that `i2` will sit immediately before `i` in memory. This assumption is baseless. Although it *happens* to be the case in your working example, when your program isn't forcing `i2` to occupy memory by taking its address (the `&i2` in your "print statement") the variable is evidently *completely optimised out*. It doesn't exist in memory *at all*!

So no wonder trying to guess at its memory location and print the value underneath said memory location is not working as you expect.

C++ is an *abstraction*. It's deliberately designed with the knowledge that this sort of thing is really the choice of your compiler and cannot be predicted ahead of time. That's why C++ says that your code has *undefined behaviour*: because it might appear to do what you want it to do, or it might skin a cat and teleport the body into your car boot, or it might transfer all your hard-earned savings into my bank account; if you want to code to standards, just avoid undefined behaviour, assume *only* the guarantees of the standard, and then all this uncertainty vanishes in a poof of catnip.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation, I'm not going to "guess" undefined behavior any more.

Comment: @piratf: Good for you :)

Comment: I love the last paragraph!